Error Code 1356 Error loading schema content
estoy aprendiendo a trabajar con vistas y store procedures en mysql. Todo iba bien pero noto que no que cada vez que actualizo me tira un error

Error Code: 1356 View 'administracion.vista_club' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them

Los ejemplos de vistas y procedures me los muestra, solo que en la parte de Output, en Workbench me sale este error.
También en el panel de la izquierda, cada vez que ingreso me sale esto:

Alguien sabe cómo puedo resolverlo? Hasta ahora, puedo seguir haciendo ejercicios, pero tengo miedo de que, más adelante no pueda continuar.

yo también eh tenido ese problema pero encontré la solución.
Error Code: 1356 View 'administracion.vista_club' En esa linea que resalta el el ERROR nos dice que hay inconveniente en la vista o vistas creadas según sea el caso, mi solución fue que borre todas las vistas y con eso puede solucionarlo.
Explicación más detallada:
Una de las tablas o columnas referenciadas en la vista "administracion.vista_club" puede haber sido eliminada o renombrada.
Verifica que todas las tablas y columnas referenciadas en la vista existan y tengan los nombres correctos. Puedes hacerlo con una consulta SHOW TABLES para verificar las tablas y SHOW COLUMNS FROM nombre_tabla para verificar las columnas.
